# How do I configure Spring Security 2 database authentication with Hibernate 3 Annotated Classes?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-security

I'm building an app using Hibernate 3 (with JPA Annotations), Spring 2.5 and Spring Security 2.0.5.

I want to know what I need to put in my `<authentication-provider>` tag in my spring security config file (applicationContext-security.xml) so that I can get Spring Security to use my existing Service layer class (AuthenticationService) which deals with my custom User and Role domain objects.

I understand that Spring Security requires two tables to be present with the following schema:

```
     create table users(
      username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null primary key,
      password varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
      enabled boolean not null);

  create table authorities (
      username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
      authority varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
      constraint fk_authorities_users foreign key(username) references users(username));

  create unique index ix_auth_username on authorities (username,authority);;
```

but I want to use my own domain objects which are different to the above table definitions.

Could someone please point me in the right direction here? I can't find any useful documentation and I'm not sure whether what I want to do is actually possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can implement a custom [`UserDetailsService`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) as a bridge between your domain and Spring Security. Then you supply Spring Security with it as follows (for Spring Security 2.x):

```
<security:authentication-provider user-service-ref='myUserDetailsService'/>

<bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="... your implementation ...">
    ...
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your custom `AutenticationManager` using `<bean id="myAuthenticationManager" class="com.security.MyAuthunticationManager"/>` and the `MyAutenticationManager` class should implement `org.springframework.security.AuthenticationManager` and override the method `authenticate(Authentication authentication)` in which you will use your custom service and domain objects to validate the user credentials and add his roles to authentication object.

Comment: It's overkill. Custom UserDetailsService is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Do what axtavt said, or if you don't need anything more than to hit a custom table, you can override the query:

```
<security:authentication-provider>
     <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" 
        authorities-by-username-query="SELECT u.username, a.authority FROM users u, authorities a WHERE u.username = a.username AND u.username = ?" />
        users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password, enabled FROM users WHERE username = ?" />
</security:authentication-provider>
```

I would do what axtavt suggest though.  You can create a DTO (Data Transfer Object) that Implements the Spring Security User object.  This will allow you to access pertinent data when retrieving the user from SecurityContextHolder:

```
Object o = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();
UserDetailsDTO u = (UserDetailsDTO) o;
User user = u.getUser();
// now you have primary key, etc., etc.
```

You really don't need that right now looking at your tables, but IMO, your schema needs work.