# Spring Security DB Authentication w/Hibernate and hashed passwords?

Tags: hibernate, authentication, hash, passwords, spring-security

I'm trying to set up spring security 3 to authenticate users against my hibernate 3 database. I'm storing only sha1 hashes of the passwords in the database (not plaintext).

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318467/how-do-i-configure-spring-security-2-database-authentication-with-hibernate-3-ann) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683308/spring-security-3-database-authentication-with-hibernate), which tell me to implement my own UserDetailsService. Unfortunately, the UserDetails that loadUserByUsername spits out seem to need the plaintext password, which I don't have.

How is this usually handled? Can Spring Security actually do what I need here? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you setup an UserDetailsService, spring uses that to load users and then compares them against the login information. That means, it compares the passwords.
However, you can configure a password encoder: [Doc: Adding a Password Encoder](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-services.html#core-services-password-encoding)

or you simply write your own [AuthenticationManager or AuthenticationProvider](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-custom-access-mgr) which loads the user and decides if the user has logged in successfully. Just implement the Interfaces 
AuthenticationProvider and set up the config

```
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="myAuthenticationProvider"
  class="stackoverflow.SuperduperMegaAuthenticationProvider">
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

Normaly the Userdetails contain a hashed password and you just need to configure Spring Security to use the correct [password encoder](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-services.html#core-services-password-encoding) to authenticate with it.

```
 <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
```

Look for the above password-encoder line in Stack Overflow answer @ [Spring Security 3 database authentication with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683308/spring-security-3-database-authentication-with-hibernate/2701722#2701722).

In you're case you should replace this line with:

```
<password-encoder hash="sha"/>
```